# Count the number of solutions of the inequality $a+b+c+d=n$, $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0$.

Tags: combinatorics

How would I count the number of integer solutions to: $a+b+c+d=n$, $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0$.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem with $a\geq b\geq c\geq d\geq 0$, we are gonna use generating functions. First note that we can write
$$
a+b+c+d=n
$$
as 
$$
a+b+c^{'}+2d=n,
$$
where we used $c=c^{'}+d$ for some $c^{'} \geq 0$ Repeating this process, we get
$$
a^{'}+2b^{'}+3c^{'}+4d^{'}=n \,\, a^{'},b^{'},c^{'},d^{'}\geq 0.
$$
Now if you are familiar with generating functions, see for example [Generating functions for combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39127/generating-functions-for-combinatorics),
you recognize that the generating function of this equation is the product of
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^4}.
$$
You seek the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series of this function. It starts like 
$$
1+x+2\,{x}^{2}+3\,{x}^{3}+5\,{x}^{4}+6\,{x}^{5}+9\,{x}^{6}+11\,{x}^{7
}+15\,{x}^{8}+18\,{x}^{9}+23\,{x}^{10}+27\,{x}^{11}
$$ 
You can find this sequence on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,2,3,5,6,9,11,15&sort=&language=&go=Search) for a greater list.