# How many ways to distribute?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways $n$ things can be distributed among $5$ persons such that no one receives more than 9 things?

$n\le 45$ and $ n\ge 5$

Please help. I failed trying all methods

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @GNU supporter I tried all methods I can't understand it anyway

Comment: This is a common kind of homework problem. Could you please mention the source and motivation of the problem, and what methods you have seen in class for solving this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to construct a generating function, for one person you would get $1+x+\ldots+x^9$ and for $5$ people you get
$$
f(x) = \left(1+\ldots+x^9\right)^5
$$
and you seek the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)$. One approach is to expand it into Taylor series ...

Comment: Can you show the proof why this works in this particular problem?

Comment: I cannot visualize it, how it works!! 

Comment: @David The generating function $f$ is constructed in a careful way to be $f(x)=a_nx^n$ where $a_n$ is exactly the number you seek for any $n$...

Comment: I still don't get the reason to sum variable x in ascending powers. Can you help me with any link which would help me to explain why such generating function is required?

Comment: Sir I accepted your answer though I didn't understand why such function is required

Comment: @David Please see this answer for related links and citations https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39129/16192